# How to just run subset of ICG tests in GPDB

Tags: greenplum

Usually, the installcheck-good is executed like:

```
make installcheck-good
```

However, if I only want to run a single test, how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Just figure it out. It's actually doable:

```
cd src/test/regress
./pg_regress <test1> <test2>
```